# ChromeDriver started but failed because: unexpected end of stream on Connection

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

Hi I have downloaded a chrome driver 115 from [download website](https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/115.0.5790.170/mac-arm64/chromedriver-mac-arm64.zip)for chrome version 115.0.5790.170

The first, the webdriver start successfully:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 115.0.5790.170 (cc0d30c2ca5577520c8646671513241faa0bc105-refs/branch-heads/5790@{#1923}) on port 9639
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1691436406.164][WARNING]: Browser-wide DevTools client failed to connect: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
```

but when the code came to create

```
DriverFactory.createDriver(customCapabilities);
```

it thrown an exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{localhost:9639, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=localhost/127.0.0.1:9639 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'xxxxxx', ip: '192.168.0.164', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '13.5', java.version: '1.8.0_361'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:92)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:147)
    at com.visa.framework.ui.DesktopDriverProvider.createDriver(DesktopDriverProvider.java:60)
    at com.visa.framework.ui.DriverFactory.createDriver(DriverFactory.java:45)
    at com.visa.vd.ui.stepdefinitions.common.Hooks.loadDriver(Hooks.java:113)
    at com.visa.vd.ui.stepdefinitions.common.Hooks.loadDriver(Hooks.java:75)
    at com.visa.vd.ui.vdportal.BaseTest.launchApplication(BaseTest.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:340)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:294)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:176)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:770)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:591)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:402)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:396)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1180)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1102)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1032)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1000)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:105)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{localhost:9639, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=localhost/127.0.0.1:9639 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:208)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:105)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: limit=0 content=…
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:237)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readHeaderLine(Http1Codec.java:215)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
    ... 55 more
```

It was confused me because it works fine in another computers(not the project issue I think), and I tested different version of chromeDriver(114), it said :

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: not connected to DevTools
  (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)
  (Session info: chrome=115.0.5790.170)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052}),platform=Mac OS X 13.5.0 arm64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 4.63 seconds
```

Can anyone help me on this issue please? really appreciate for any advise! please let me know if you need anything, thank you!